# SSIS 2008 information warning when executing a package

Tags: ssis

Has anybody already faced a message like:

> Information while loading package1:The package is attempting to configure from the XML  file \xxxx\yyyyy\package1.dtsconfig

So I did set a configuration file to my package but I'm just wondering why I got this message even though the package is successfully executed.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behaviour. There is an option per package to suppress this message, 
[SuppressConfigurationWarnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.package.suppressconfigurationwarnings.aspx)

If you don't want to edit your packages, you can try the SET option on package invocation `/SET "\Package.Properties[SuppressConfigurationWarnings]";1`

Comment: +1 for including both ways to suppress the message. Though one would think the message is self-explanatory and neither a warning nor an error, so the purpose of suppressing it is only to reduce the noise and prevent others from needing to look this answer up in SO :-).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is not a warning, just some information.

It is useful when debugging to help you make sure it is loading the correct configurations. If it failed to load the configurations you would have a a 'real' warning saying that it failed to load the configurations from said file.

This also happens when using parent package variables

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is an info message that the configuration is being loaded but Its the first time I'm seeing it even though I use configuration files all the time. Are you sure your config file is ok? Can you post it here so we can take a look?